# Uploading a image to a server + inserting filename to dB

Tags: php, upload

The php:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "/images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$strListItemPic=(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " 
      has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {
//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

The html:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
    <input type="file" name="photo">
```

It's breaking out and giving `"Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";`

I'm inserting $strListItemPic later in a MySQL statement, so I can echo the picture in a variable elsewhere.

Any glaring errors in this code? Does my $target have to be absolute paths?

PHP errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/xxxxxx/lists/images/test.gif): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/virtual/site48/fst/var/www/html/xxxxxx/lists/itemedit.php on line 22


Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpJ3v7HV' to 
'/xxxxxx/lists/images/test.gif' 
in /home/virtual/site48/fst/var/www/html/xxxxxx/lists/itemedit.php on line 22
```

Fixed:

```
Added enctype="multipart/form-data" to  <form>
Removed / before images in $target
```

Comment: Does apache have write access in the directory. Does the directory exist? What do your logs say?

Comment: Why it was tagged with mysql?

Comment: Ensure that FORM tag has right entype - "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Added enctype to form data, currently set to multipart/form-data

Comment: does it work when you use absolute paths?

Comment: It's working now. turned out to be "multipart/form-data"

Comment: -1 as it cannot be multipart/form-data issue. If it was, there wouldn't be a '/tmp/phpJ3v7HV' file at all.

Comment: now it looks a real one. +1 then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors don't have to glare in the code.
Errors being raised at the time the code gets executed.
And these errors have to be noted and investigated.

at least add these 2 lines into your code and run it again.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or get the error message produced by move_uploaded_file any other way.
Trying to answer your question without an actual error message would be useless waste of time.

Comment: Thanks Shrapnel, I'll not this down. Updated my Question with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache sub directory where you write (move)images must be writable i.e have permissions to write files. since it looks like you are on Linux cd to the directory and change permissions with:
cd /the/parent/directory/to/directory/where/files/are/supposed/to/be
chmod 777 theimagefilesdir/

Be sure to read permissions and choose one that fits you as 777 is very permissive and can be impractical to production but I use it in my local machine :)

Comment: well sometimes I feel I should not contribute here at SO. How could someone downvote this answer when one of errors clearly says: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpJ3v7HV' to 
'/xxxxxx/lists/images/test.gif' ??
Is my answer irrelevant? I think ability to downvote is being misused here!

Comment: sure it is. when it's going to be a permissions issue, the move_uploaded_file() plainly says,"failed to open stream: **Permission denied** in...". But this one says "No such file or directory". May be you are right in your desire and have to wait until you get enough experience.

Answer (score -1):

Please check that you are using enctype in form tag